# How to translate dates to Spanish?

Tags: traducción, tiempo

I want to make questions about calendar. I will show the calendar of January and ask those questions in Spanish.

How can I ask these questions in Spanish.

> Q1: Today is Jan. 15. What date was last Monday?
> Q2: Today is Jan. 15. What date is next Monday?
> Q3: How many Mondays are there?
> Q4: How man days are there in January?
> Q5: What day of week is Jan. 15?
> Q6: What date is second Monday?

I translated like this. however, I am not sure it is right.

> Q1: Hoy es el 15 de enero. ¿Qué día es el próximo lunes?
>
> Q2: Hoy es el 15 de enero. ¿Qué día fue el lunes pasado?
>
> Q3: ¿Cuántas lunes hay?
>
> Q4: ¿Cuántos días hay en enero?
>
> Q5: ¿Que dia es 15 de enero?
>
> Q6: ¿En qué fecha es el primavera lunes?

Please let me know

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It is a little bit difficult to understand what is giving you trouble. Could you please try to translate them into Spanish yourself first? By doing that we won't just give you a "translation service" but will help you understand what you really need. By seeing what gives you trouble we can give you more meaningful answers.

Comment: I translated like this. however, I am not sure it is right.
    Q1: Hoy es el 15 de enero. ¿Qué día es el próximo lunes?
    Q2: Hoy es el 15 de enero. ¿Qué día fue el lunes pasado?
    Q3: ¿Cuántas lunes hay? 
    Q4: ¿Cuántos días hay en enero? 
    Q5: ¿Que dia es 15 de enero?
    Q6: ¿En qué fecha es el primavera lunes?

Comment: Thank you Mark. Great job! I see that fedorqui has already included this in the original question and posted an answer. I hope that it helps. If not don't hesitate to ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translations are almost all OK.

> Q1: Today is Jan. 15. What date was last Monday?
>
> Q2: Hoy es el 15 de enero. ¿Qué día fue el lunes pasado?

and

> Q2: Today is Jan. 15. What date is next Monday?
>
> Q1: Hoy es el 15 de enero. ¿Qué día es el próximo lunes?

Your translations were correct, but it looks like you swapped them. Notice how I moved them to their proper places.

> Q3: How many Mondays are there?
>
> Q3: ¿Cuántas lunes hay?

"Lunes" as a day is masculine, so you have to say "cuánt**o**s".

> Q4: How many days are there in January?
>
> Q4: ¿Cuántos días hay en enero?

This is fine.

> Q5: What day of week is Jan. 15?
>
> Q5: ¿Que dia es 15 de enero?

To make it more complete I would say, "¿Qué día de la semana es el 15 de enero?" or "¿Qué día de semana es el 15 de enero?". Note the diacritics on both "día" and "qué".

> Q6: What date is second Monday?
>
> Q6: ¿En qué fecha es el primer lunes?

You seem to be on the right track here but by accident you wrote "primer" instead of "segundo."